# latest something / the latest something

Tags: articles, headlinese

Example ([Russia 'is building military base in Syria'](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/syria/11846382/Russia-is-building-military-base-in-Syria.html)):

> American officials express concern about **latest intelligence** suggesting Moscow is preparing to send hundreds of personnel to prop up Assad regime.

I don't understand why it's not *THE latest intelligence*. *latest* is the superlative form of the adjective *late* and those types of grammatical forms of adjectives usually require definite articles.

Comment: This use is very common in headlines, titles and captions, to save space. Check out questions under the tag [tag:headlinese].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headlines are frequently shortened to save space ("headlinese"). It is not strictly grammatically correct, but it retains enough information to be readable. Some of the most frequent words to drop from a headline are the articles (e.g. "the"). There are two places in this headline where a "the" was removed. The full sentence might be:

> American officials express concern about **the** latest intelligence suggesting **that** Moscow is preparing to send hundreds of personnel to prop up **the** Assad regime.